# .NET Type Library for VB 6

Tags: vb6, typelib

I currently am using a .NET type library with vb 6 via a reference to it via Project -> References. I would like to make it more independent. I am curious whether I can access this library via a statement like this:

```
Public Declare Function Encode Lib "typelibrary.tlb" (ByVal intfilename As String,_
ByVal outfilename As String) As Integer
```

I haven't been able to find any reference to this and I haven't been able to get it to work myself. When I try it says: Error:53, File not found: typelibrary.tlb.

Comment: The target library (Lib) must be a library (e.g. DLL).  Trying to pass the name of a typelib here isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not access COM interfaces using a `Declare Function`. When using a COM object, you can either use early binding where you add a reference to the typelibrary/DLL, or late binding where you don't and use `CreateObject("AssemblyName.ClassName")`, but you loose intellisense, etc.

Alternatively, you can use `[DllExport]` in .Net which you can then call with VB6's `Declare Function`, but you then need to manually convert every call you need to make.